# Context menu signal handling upgrade from PyQt4 to PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qmenu

I can't find anything about how to convert the following `PyQt4` signal handling for the context menu to `PyQt5` since [this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#old-style-signals-and-slots) change:

```
self.listMenu = QMenu()

menu_item_add = self.listMenu.addAction("Add Item")

self.listMenu.connect(menu_item_add, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.menu_item_add_clicked)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [new style](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html) of connection between signals and slot, the structure is as follows:

```
{sender}.{signal}.connect({receiver}.{slot})
```

In your case:

```
menu_item_add.triggered.connect(self.menu_item_add_clicked)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's always the simple solution that evades me, and in this instance my IDE wasn't providing introspection for `triggered` since I didn't have the `()` at the end. I was trying to do stuff like `menu_item_add.triggered(self.menu_item_add_clicked)`